# How to set permit_params for another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin

These are my models:

**Product.rb**:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :position
  has_many :products_sizes
  has_many :sizes, through: :products_sizes
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products_sizes
end
```

**Products_size.rb**:

```
class ProductsSize < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :size
  has_many :prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
end
```

**Size.rb**:

```
class Size < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products_sizes
  has_many :products, through: :products_sizes
end
```

and **Price.rb**:

```
class Price < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :products_size
end
```

In ActiveAdmin I need to make a form for Product, for when I update the product, I could create a Price, so a part of the form looks like this:

```
... #here is the begining of the form
f.inputs 'Sizes' do
          f.semantic_fields_for ProductsSize.where(product_id: params[:id], size_id: Product.find(params[:id]).products_sizes.size.to_i).first.prices.new do |ps|
            ps.input :products_size_id, label: 'Size', as: :select, collection: Product.find(params[:id]).sizes.map { |s| ["#{s.title}", s.id] }
            ps.input :quantity
            ps.input :amount
            li do
              link_to 'Add size', '#'
            end
          end
        end
```

It's all seems to be good, except when clicking the submit button, the Price isn't created. I think, that's because the `permit_params` are not specified for `price`. How can I specify them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Post do
   permit_params :title,
                 comments_attributes: [:name, :hidden]
 end
```

Post is a moodel and comments is another. You can use params from comments with comments_attributes, if your model name is price you can use price_attributes: [...params...].

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you allow parameters in `active admin`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
permit_params :title, :content, :author
end
```

This is just an example, use your own params

Comment: Yes, but I need to set  `permit_params` not for my `Product` model, but for `Price`, which has `belongs_to :products_size` relation. I reach `Price` through `ProductsSize` model.

Comment: did you allow the params in your controller?